# Node.js Multicast Client

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron, multicast

So I have a camera outputting a udp multicast stream on my local network, and I know it is working correctly because I can connect to the stream through VLC Media Player via the MRL "udp://@{multicast_addr}:{port}.

I want to write a NodeJS client that will at least acknowledge that it is receiving these udp packets, but I can't seem to get it right. From other stackoverflow posts, this is what I have so far.

```
// Working MRL in VLC: udp://@{multicast_addr}:{port}

var PORT = {port};
var HOST = '{local_addr}';
var dgram = require('dgram');
var client = dgram.createSocket('udp4');

client.on('listening', function () {
    var address = client.address();
    console.log('UDP Client listening on ' + address.address + ":" + address.port);
    client.setBroadcast(true);
    client.setMulticastTTL(64); 
    client.addMembership('{multicast_addr}', HOST);
});

client.on('message', function (message, remote) {   
    console.log("Packet received")
});

client.bind(PORT, HOST);
```

When I run this, I get the message "UDP Client listening on {local_addr}:{port}" but then no "Packet received" messages. Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong? Am I misunderstanding how a udp multicast stream works?

Thank you to anyone who can help.

EDIT:

Okay so I got it to work, but I don't understand how. On the last line, instead of binding (PORT, HOST), I bound (PORT, {multicast_addr}). On running it, my console flooded with "Packet received" messages and I'm now even more confused than before.

If anyone would care to explain, I would be very grateful.

Comment: Were you ever able to get fully working and/or playing the video stream?

Answer (score 0):

In `addMembership(MADDR, HOST)`, HOST is an interface reference, the system is going to lookup the physical interface associated and make sure it is subscribed using that interface.

In `bind(PORT , HOST)`, HOST is now the only IP for your socket, if it isn't all addresses (0.0.0.0 in v4, which is also the default if the argument is omitted), you are filtering out packets to any other IPs, even if they are arriving for non-unicast reasons.

If you want to send and receive on the same socket then you will need to not bind it to a specific address, but it is usually better form to use a separate socket to send so they can be adjusted independently.